# Embedded Jetty not rendering JSP code found in *.html files

Tags: html, jsp, embedded-jetty

My application with embedded jetty server is not rendering jsp pages.

Basically my jsp pages are with the html file extension (say, `component-jsp-example.html`) and when I request the html file (which has the jsp code) the jsp code was properly translating to html code before.

But recently that is not happening for some unknown reasons and the jsp tag code is literally seen in the browser 'view-source' and in the browser the jsp tag code is rendered as-is like below.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://example.com/xyz" prefix="xyz"%>
```

The same translation is working fine in other environments, appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

JSP files are processed by the [`JettyJspServlet`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.12.v20160915/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L280) with the [following url-patterns](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.12.v20160915/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L310-L320).

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xsp</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.JSP</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.JSPF</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.JSPX</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.XSP</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To support JSP processing of `*.html`, you'll have to add that mapping yourself.

> Note: adding `*.html` url-pattern to JSP will invalidate the performance enhancements of serving static files from the `DefaultServlet`.